# Need the name value of the enterprise to be the same as it was when it was registered and not the value it currently has

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I will explain the problem with an example: I am designing a specific case of referential integrity in a table. In the logical design there are two tables, `enterprise` and `document`. We register the companies and then someone inserts the documents associated with it. The name of the enterprise is variable.

When it comes to recovering the documents, I need the name value of an enterprise to be the same as it was when it was registered and not the value it currently has.

The solution that I thought was to register the company again in each change with the same code, the updated name in this way would have the expected result, but I am not sure if it is the best solution. Can someone make a suggestion? 
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `numeric(19,0)` instead of `bigint`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply store the register_name (meaning the first value that was taken by the name of the enterprise) in the enterprise table :

- identerprise
- code
- name
- register_name

Then I think you shouldn't use varchar(n) to store your text value (see that [documentation page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Text_storage))